# How can i get item in a listBox but the item name and not index?

Tags: c#

```
string ff = "";
        private IntPtr GetProcessIntptr()
        {
            listBoxSnap.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                ff = listBoxSnap.Items[this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            }));
            int index1 = ff.IndexOf("Handle: ");
            ff = ff.Substring(index1 + 8);
            int handle = Int32.Parse(ff);
            IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)handle;

            return ptr;
        }
```

Instead of using the index:

```
ff = listBoxSnap.Items[this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

I want to get the item name i know the item name but how do i get it ?

Comment: What i meant is to get a specific item name.  I did it be using a foreach a string in the listbox items and then i'm checking in the loop for example if (item == "this is the item name i wanted") then do something.

Comment: If you already have the name what are you searching for?

Comment: You should change your question to show that you are wanting help to replace your loop. The code your are showing in your question doesn't actually match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list box is simply a list of strings:

```
var item = listBoxSnap.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i == "nameToBeFound");
```

If your list box contains a list of objects with a name property:

```
var item = listBoxSnap.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.name == "nameToBeFound");
```

Item will now be either null if there is no such item or the item for which you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
listBoxSnap.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx